# How to retrieve information from localStorage to pass to database

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to get information from localStorage to pass to a database in my application. I type "localStorage" into the console and it shows the proper value so I believe it is there for retrieval. However, I am not able to get the data for some reason. Right now, the variable rfidText is being set by keyboard input. I want to set it by grabbing the string in "userID" in localStorage. Below I have in a comment what I have tried that is not working. I call localStorage.setItem() in the file1 and localStorage.getItem() in file2: Any ideas why? My javascript for file 1 is:

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery*/

$(document).ready(function () {

    "use strict";
    var scanned = false,
    scannedInput = [];

    $(window).keypress(function (scanEvent) {

        if (scanEvent.which >= 48 && scanEvent.which <= 57) {
            scannedInput.push(String.fromCharCode(scanEvent.which));
        }

        setTimeout(function () {

            if (scannedInput.length === 10) {

                var userID = scannedInput.join("");
                scanned = true;
                window.localStorage.setItem('userID', userID);
                $("#userId").val(userID);

                if (scanned) {
                    window.location.href = "../html/registration.html";
                }
            }

        scannedInput = [];

        }, 500);
    });
});
```

And the file 2 javascript is:

```
console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('userID')); // this prints
var rfidText = window.localStorage.getItem('userID');
console.log(rfidText);  // this doesn't print

var avatarText = "";

var config = {
    apiKey: xxx  //private info
    authDomain: xxx //private info
    databaseURL: xxx //private info
    storageBucket: xxx //private info
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var database = firebase.database();

function setAvatar(avatarName) {
    avatarText = avatarName;
    console.log(avatarText);
}

function writeToFirebase(idInput, languageInput, avatarInput, nameInput, 
ageGroupInput) {

    database.ref("RFID/" + idInput).set({
        id: idInput,
        language: languageInput,
        avatar: avatarInput,
        name: nameInput,
    ageGroup: ageGroupInput,
});
}

function update() {

    var rfidText = document.getElementById("rfidInput").value;

    /* instead of the line above, I want to set rfidText with this line
    var rfidText = localStorage.getItem("userID");  << doesn't work */

    var languageText = document.getElementById("languageInput").value;
    var nameText = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
    var ageGroupText = document.getElementById("ageGroupInput").value;

    writeToFirebase(rfidText, languageText, avatarText, nameText, 
    ageGroupText);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running `localStorage.getItem("userID")` in the console? It seems that should work if localStorage has a value for the key "userID".

Comment: Are you sure `localStorage.setItem("userID", "some_id")` is called _**before**_ `update` function is called?

Comment: @TheThirdOne I typed localStorage.getItem("userID") into the console and it returns the proper value.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb localStorage.setItem("userID", "some_id") is set in the previous page's javascript file.

Comment: please update your post with "console output" after you type "localStorage"

Comment: So I added three new lines to the top of my file 2 above. The first line prints in the console, but not the third line.

Comment: In response to my post above: I had placed console.log statements throughout the code and they were not printing while I was trying to debug. A friend pointed out that the browser was probably using a cached version of the page. As it turns out, after I used the browser in incognito mode (Chrome) the print statements were in fact working. I'm not sure why, but trying to set rfidText inside the function update() resulted in the variable being set to null. I set the variable outside the function as a global variable and it was set properly and was usable in my writeToFirebase().

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This example can be tested in this link: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local

For more about local storage give a look at this link https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

For multiple saves in local storage you can use the example in the link: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FG2UNYNWBO2D

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
    localStorage.setItem("firstname", "Luis");
    localStorage.setItem("age", "28 years hold");
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("firstname")+" "+localStorage.getItem("lastname")+" "+localStorage.getItem("age");
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want you can save a json, example in link https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FG2VMMBWMZW6

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
// Check browser support
var string = {"firstname":"Luis", "lastname": "Smith", "Age": "28 years old"};
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(string));
    // Retrieve
    console.debug(localStorage.getItem("data"));
    var objdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
    console.debug(objdata);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = objdata.firstname + "  "+ objdata.lastname + " " + objdata.Age;
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Explanation by steps:

1)Create a json `{"firstname":"Luis", "lastname": "Smith", "Age": "28 years old"};`

2)Save the json as string in the local storage `localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(string));`

3) Get data from storage and json parse `var objdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));`

4)Use the data in the Json  `objdata.Age`

For multipel data in the Json, example in the link https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FG2VX2M9XKMR

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
// Check browser support
var string = {"firstname":["Luis","Peter"], "lastname": ["Smith","Maerques"], "Age": ["28 years old", "29 years old"]};
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(string));
    // Retrieve
    console.debug(localStorage.getItem("data"));
    var objdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
    console.debug(objdata);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = objdata.firstname[1] + " " + objdata.lastname[0] + " " + objdata.Age[1];
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The difference to the previous example is that now I save data arrays in my Json.

Json:

```
 {"firstname":["Luis","Peter"], "lastname": ["Smith","Maerques"], "Age": ["28 years old", "29 years old"]};
```

When using Json data, you must enter the number of the index array .

```
objdata.firstname[1]
```

If you want the size of the array, use this code

```
objdata.firstname.length
```

Any questions, just ask that I will try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set using `localStorage.setItem("key","value");`

You can get it using `localStorage.getItem("key");`

You can remove it using `localStorage.removeItem("key");`

Comment: I have tried this in the code above. It doesn't work.

Comment: In browser console can run localStorage.getItem("userID")?? adn tell me what you got?

Comment: It shows me the correct value that was added by setItem("userID", userID" 
wher userID is set by a string.

Comment: do you have any error in browser console? if it is set in localStorage then problem with your code where you are trying to access.

Comment: I have editied my post to include the code from the file where I call setItem(). @Dinesh, I didn't see any error.

Comment: var rfidText = localStorage.getItem("userID"); what is the value of rfidText?

Comment: At the top of my file, I have
    console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('userID'));
and it shows the proper value. However, it doesn't get sent to the database. My database just shows "" for the value.

Comment: If I refresh the registration page (file 2 above) the console shows: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check xhr.spec.whatwg.org.

Comment: I edited my file 2 (registration page) above, the first line prints in the console, however the third line does not.